# Modify resource for String table type in win32 native exe

Tags: winapi, resources, exe, string-table

I want to modify some string in my `exe` resource. That resource type is a string table,
but when i use `UpdateResource` function i don't  know  what parameter must be pass to it so it's pointing to the exact raw in the string table.

The type parameter is `RT_STRING`, but what should I send to `MAKEINTRESOURCEW()`?

```
HANDLE hExeFile = BeginUpdateResource(L"d:\\m.exe", FALSE);
WCHAR mail[]={L"ddddddd@gmail.com"};
UpdateResource(hExeFile,RT_STRING,MAKEINTRESOURCEW(?????), MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), (LPVOID)mail, wcslen(mail)*2);
EndUpdateResource(hExeFile, FALSE);
```

Comment: maybe the code you have could help

Comment: possible duplicate of [updating a string table with UpdateResource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088057/updating-a-string-table-with-updateresource)

Answer (score 1):

An exe file cannot update its own resources while it is running.  The resources are locked by the OS and are read-only.  But if you could update the resources, then obviously you have to know the ID of your resource in order to update it.  If it is a compiler-generated resource, then you are probably out of luck unless your compiler uses a predictable ID number, like 1.  Otherwise, use an .rc file to define your own resource data, then you can use whatever ID you want.